# Restrict network access for remote computer

Tags: linux, linux-networking, internet

I have a remote office which has some computers which cannot have regular internet access, however, I will need to periodically access the computers remotely for which I plan to use VNC.

What is a good way to make sure the computers have no internet access except my inbound VNC connections?

My first thought here would be to configure a router ahead of them so that the router only allows ARP/DNS and the VNC port(s) 5000+N, and blocks all other ports in and out. Would that be an effective solution?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know leaving VNC port opened to the world (0.0.0.0/0) is non-secure and hackable.

Things you can do:

1. Install a firewall and configure NAT - allowing you to access the network through the VNC port but only to one specific IP (and not to the world).
2. Configure a VPN server which will let you reach all hosts within the network once you're connected to it.

Using both solutions you can limit users access to the internet and allowing access to specific services within the network.

Comment: How is it hackable? You mean if someone guesses the username/password for the VNC account?

Comment: For example, yea.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just give them bogus DNS entries and leave all IP/subnet/Gateway info intact?  That will break their attempts to browse but leave routable traffic.  Bad DNS will break patching and probably other applications, but you can easily turn that on and off.

Comment: That's an idea, but one concern is that even a minimal Linux client opens up a lot of ports on the machine and I would like to avoid those ports being accessible from the internet.

Answer (score 0):

My usual setup in these cases is to have a router in front of the network that you can SSH into, and then use SSH port forward only when you need to access the internal computers.

Routers like Mikrotik or Ubiquiti have such capability and usually are really affordable. In such setup, you could have the computers you want to keep off the Internet get only IP addresses by DHCP and no IP for a gateway. This way they will be able to communicate with other computers in the same network, but have no path to reach the Internet.

When you need to access these internal computers from the outside world, you SSH into the router and use local port forward, something like this:

`user@admin-computer:~$ ssh router.company.com -f -L 5900:<no-inet-pc1-ip>:5900`

and after logging in with your SSH user/password, you start your VNC client and connect to 127.0.0.1 at the standard 5900 port and you will be reaching the internal PC (which has `no-inet-pc1-ip` IP address) on the VNC port. This will work even without a gateway on the internal PCs because the connection from their point of view come from the router, not your remote `admin-computer`

If you setup SSH with publickey authentication (strongly recommended) and use non-standard port for SSH on the router (to avoid for the continuous scan that happens to port 22) you will have an affordable, secure and automateable setup without having to setup VPNs o complex firewalling.

Hope it helps!